# Counting up when saving

Tags: ios, directory, save

I am saving an image however it is just duplicating itself since I only set only one name however I want it to count up so that it wont replace itself.  Is there any way to do this?

```
    NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder

    for (int i = 0; i < [directoryNames count] ; i++) {
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]; //Create folder

        NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"]; // "right" is at index 2, per comments & code
        NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats.PNG"]; // you maybe want to incorporate a timestamp into the name to avoid duplicates
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Check the number of files in hats folder. Get its count with ++ and append it with the file to be saved name.

Comment: I know that its just replacing itself but I don't know how to stop that using timestamp or something else which is more simpler

Answer (score 2):

Use timestamp value as filename to avoid duplicates

Comment: You mean this code rite?`time_t unixTime = (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *timestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",unixTime];`However do I just put it under at the same place.  I don't think it will work updating the name of the picture